# How to queue up Windows 8 file coping to only have one copying at a time

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, file-management, file-transfer

The new windows 8 file explorer copying is great. I can setup multiple copying tasks. They appear in a single window and I am able to pause them.

Is there a way to have the copying only occur one at a time and when complete to progress the next one?

Currently I have to setup the file copy and pause subsequent ones, then unpause the next one when I notice the current one finishes.

I am only asking about a way to queue the file explorer coping and not use alternative tools like robocopy.

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft are adding all sorts of unnecessary stuffs like XBox Music to Windows, instead of implementing/improving this kind of feature that an OS should provide. It took 15 years for them to add "pause copying" since Windows 95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the default windows copying doesn't have a queuing process.

> What neither Linux nor Windows 8 have is a queue feature.

You can check [here](http://www.itworld.com/open-source/248654/8-best-innovations-windows-8-borrowed-linux) for more details. You will find many third party applications for this purpose (TeraCopy). You can use any one of them. But this is a nice to  have feature in the current edition of WIndows 8 where you have a checkbox which says "Queue copying" or something similar.